# How to retrieve Excel data From Query

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I have converted Excel data into a PHP array using `toArray()` and then loaded that data into a datatable:

[image]

But I want to retrive the data from Excel in DB query based like

**query**`(SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE degree = 'X' AND degree = 'XII')`

How can I apply a query on Excel data? OR How can I apply a query for PHP multidimensonal array? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Your query is not correct, at the same time a column can't has the two different value, or you should use from `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: Actually, you should use IN()

Comment: If the data is in a PHP array, then logically you might use an [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) or tools like LINQ